# How would I capture a specific amount of numerical characters within a function in R?

Tags: r, match, grepl

I'm sure the wording of my question could be better, but this is the scenario i'm dealing with.

My current data looks like this:

```
     v1    v2    v3    v4
1   abc   def    1     1
2   abc   def    1     1
3   1990  def    0     1
```

*v3* and *v4* return 1 when *v1* or *v2* is 'abc' or 'def'. I have numerous instances in my dataset where  there are years listed in the typical 4 digit context (ex: 1960, 1990, 2000). How can I include these in my code to return a '1' for v3 and v4 regardless of the date?

This is my current code:

```
df$v3 <- as.integer(grepl"(^abc$|^def$)", df$v1))
df$v4 <- as.integer(grepl"(^abc$|^def$)", df$v2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I'm interpreting your desired output correctly, you want v3 to be 1 if v1 is 'abc' or 'def' or a 4-digit year, and you want v4 to be 1 if v2 is 'abc' or 'def' or a 4-digit year, correct?

If so, then instead of having your regex just look for the exact strings 'abc' or 'def', you can have it look for a 4-digit number as well.

```r
df$v3 <- as.integer(grepl("(^abc$|^def$|^[[:digit:]]{4}$)", df$v1))
df$v4 <- as.integer(grepl("(^abc$|^def$|^[[:digit:]]{4}$)", df$v2))
```

Comment: That is correct, I will run the code now and get back to you.

Comment: A more compact regex would be `^(?:abc|def|\\d{4})$`.

Comment: @llottmanhill worked perfectly thank you! Off the scope of the original question, but do you know how could I report a 1 in v3/v4 if v1/v2 happened to contain a null value?

Comment: @Junitar would your syntax essentially be the same without having to do ^x$ for every variable?

Comment: @MaxH. Yeah, inside your as.integer function, you could check for a regex match or a missing value.  For example, `as.integer(grepl("(^abc$|^def$|^[[:digit:]]{4}$)", df$v1)|is.na(df$v1))`

Comment: @Max H. It's exactly the same regex written in a more compact way. `(?:)` is a non capturing group. What comes before or/and after it will apply to all the components in that group. `\\d` is the shorthand for `[[:digit:]]`.